# Javascript code running in order

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im having issues with my JS code not running in order. It skips to the `if(!hadError)` before it executes the catch when there is an error so that hadError is always equal to true. I know is has to do with javascript and how it runs things simultaneously but im not sure how to fix it.
Here is the code:

```
var email = $('#email').val();
var password = $('#password').val();
var hadError = false;
// var unlocked = false;

if(email != "" && password != ""){
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // console.log(hadError);
    hadError = true;
    console.log(hadError);
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    $('#login-error').text(errorMessage);
    // unlocked = true;
  });
  if(!hadError){
    success();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase methods are asynchronous and return `Promise`'s. You can do a .then() on after the method call to execute code after the Promise is returned, e.g.

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => { 
    //if you want, do something with the `user` which is a firebase.User
    if(!hadError) success();
}).catch(function(error) {
    hadError = true;
    console.log(hadError);
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    $('#login-error').text(errorMessage);
});
```

Depending on the method you may not even need to check `hadError`.

For further reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

In some cases you can pass a second method to `then` that is called if the `Promise` is rejected, but for Firebase the method that the API refers to is `catch` for error handling.